# Does sitecore 9.0.2 supports Azure SQL managed instance(Azure SQL Paas)?

Tags: installation, sql-database

Does sitecore 9.0.2 supports Azure SQL managed instance(Azure SQL Paas) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sitecore 9.0.2 does support Azure SQL. The KB page is a little outdated, but Sitecore 9.0.2 fully supports Azure SQL.

From their compatibility KB page:  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/777703

> Sitecore supports Microsoft Azure SQL Database service for the
>   following setups:
>
> When running Sitecore XP 8.2 and later versions.
>
> When running Sitecore XP 8.1 and earlier versions and deploying to
>   Microsoft Azure using the Sitecore Azuremodule.
>
> Sitecore does not support using Azure SQL Databases in the following
>   situations:
>
> When using Email Experience Manager module **prior to Sitecore 9.0.1 (not mentioned in link)**
>
> When running any configuration that is not mentioned in the supported
>   list.